# MouseOrbit Customization: Place camera on spot orbit

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a MouseOrbit script based on the Standard Assets Script that I need to customize to place the camera in a specific spot in the orbit.

Heres the basics of the standard script that ships with Unity3d:

> ```c#
> function Start () {
>
>     var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
>     x = angles.y;
>     y = angles.x;
>
>     // Make the rigid body not change rotation
>     if (rigidbody)
>         rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;   
> }
>
> function onUpdate(){
>
>     x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * xSpeed;
>     y -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * ySpeed;
>
>     var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x,0);
>     var position = rotation * Vector3(0.0, 0.0, cameraDelta); 
>
>     transform.rotation = rotation;
>     transform.position = position; 
> }
> ```

What I need to do is place the camera in a few spots around the target object at `0,0`.

The first is directly behind the object. `x:7,:y0,z:0`.

Here's what I thought would work:

> ```c#
> function TransformCamera(x,y,z){
>
>     //set position of camera
>     transform.position  = new Vector3(x, y, z);
>
>     var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
>     y = angles.y;
>     x = angles.x;
>     z = angles.z;
>
>     var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y, x, z);
>     var position = rotation * Vector3(0.0, 0.0, cameraDelta);
>     //adjusted_target;
>
>     transform.rotation = rotation;
>     transform.position = position;
> }
> ```

This script is close... it transforms the camera and rotates it to look at the object, but it doesn't place the camera in the correct location `7,0,0`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this modified  script. i hope this will solve your problem.

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OrbitCamera : MonoBehaviour
{

    //The target of the camera. The camera will always point to this object.
    public Transform _target;

    //The default distance of the camera from the target.
    private float _distance ;

    //Control the speed of zooming and dezooming.
    public float _zoomStep = 1.0f;

    //The speed of the camera. Control how fast the camera will rotate.
    public float _xSpeed = 1f;
    public float _ySpeed = 1f;

    //The position of the cursor on the screen. Used to rotate the camera.
    private float _x = 0.0f;
    private float _y = 0.0f;

    //Distance vector.
    private Vector3 _distanceVector;

    /**
     * Move the camera to its initial position.
     */
    void Start ()
    {
        _distanceVector = new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,-this.transform.position.z);
        _distance = this.transform.position.z;
        Vector2 angles = this.transform.localEulerAngles;
        _x = angles.x;
        _y = angles.y;

        this.Rotate(_x, _y);
    }

    /**
     * Rotate the camera or zoom depending on the input of the player.
     */
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if ( _target )
        {
            this.RotateControls();
            this.Zoom();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Rotate the camera when the first button of the mouse is pressed.
     *
     */
    void RotateControls()
    {
        if ( Input.GetButton("Fire1") )
        {
            _x += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _xSpeed;
            _y += -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")* _ySpeed;

            this.Rotate(_x,_y);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Transform the cursor mouvement in rotation and in a new position
     * for the camera.
     */
    void Rotate( float x, float y )
    {
        //Transform angle in degree in quaternion form used by Unity for rotation.
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(y,x,0.0f);

        //The new position is the target position + the distance vector of the camera
        //rotated at the specified angle.
        Vector3 position = rotation * _distanceVector + _target.position;

        //Update the rotation and position of the camera.
        transform.rotation = rotation;
        transform.position = position;
    }

    /**
     * Zoom or dezoom depending on the input of the mouse wheel.
     */
    void Zoom()
    {
        if ( Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") < 0.0f )
        {
            this.ZoomOut();
        }
        else if ( Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") > 0.0f )
        {
             this.ZoomIn();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Reduce the distance from the camera to the target and
     * update the position of the camera (with the Rotate function).
     */
    void ZoomIn()
    {
        _distance -= _zoomStep;
        _distanceVector = new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,-_distance);
        this.Rotate(_x,_y);
    }

    /**
     * Increase the distance from the camera to the target and
     * update the position of the camera (with the Rotate function).
     */
    void ZoomOut()
    {
        _distance += _zoomStep;
        _distanceVector = new Vector3(0.0f,0.0f,-_distance);
        this.Rotate(_x,_y);
    }

} //End class
```